Laptop SIM card
I have a HP laptop and my operating system is Ubuntu. My laptop uses a SIM card and I want to use SIM card internet. There is a SIM card tab on the settings page but it says there is no SIM card and writes insert a sim card to use this modem!!

Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

This question is similar to: Laptop SIM card slot not recognized. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
